# How to solve: $4^x=3^x+1$

Tags: exponential-function

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, solve for $x$:

$$
4^x=3^x+1
$$

By inspection, it's easy to see that $x=1$ is a solution. How would I go about showing that it is the only solution? If I look at the graph it's quite obvious, but I don't see how I can do it formally.

Comment: Show that the derivative on the left exceeds the derivative on the right.

Comment: This is a popular question on the web, e.g., see [here](https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Precalculus/437275).

Comment: You are lucky $x=1$ works. Otherwise the exact solution doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x>1$, then $4^x >4\cdot 3^{x-1} = (3+1)3^{x-1}=3^x + 3^{x-1}\geq 3^x+1$.

Let me know if any of the steps are unclear.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I guess I still have to show that $4^x<3^x+1$ for $x < 1$, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, I just realized I forgot that part :) If you are having trouble figuring it out, I can update the answer!

Comment: Seems to be almost identical: $x < 1 \implies 4^x=4\cdot 4^{x-1} < 4\cdot 3^{x-1} = 3^x + 3^{x-1} < 3^x + 1$. I'll accept your answer after the grace period has passed. Thanks again.